# Validation in Lost focus event

Tags: wpf, vb.net

we are having wpf pages which has a menu items on the top with select,save,clear,exit items. Below the menu we have got a textbox which accepts the supplier code. In the lost focus of the textbox we have to validate the supplier code is correct and at the same time if user clicks the exit menu item this validation should not happen. this has been easily achieved by checking the tab index in the windows application but in WPF pages we dont know how to achieve.Below code is done in the windows application.same functionality we need in the wpf pages.

we need code in c#

```
Private Sub txtSupp_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSupp.Leave
  If Me.ActiveControl Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If Me.ActiveControl.TabIndex <= txtSupp.TabIndex And _
  Me.ActiveControl.Parent.TabIndex <= txtSupp.Parent.TabIndex Then Exit Sub
  Dim lsErrmsg As String
  cowSIMaintain.Validate_Supp(Me, lsErrmsg)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but in wpf pages your syntax will not work. only in windows application this will works.

Comment: sorry, Updated my answer with a working wpf answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void txtSupp_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var focusedControl = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
        if (focusedControl.GetType() == typeof(Button))
        {
            var but = focusedControl as Button;
            if (but == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (but.Name == "ImTheExitButton")
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        string lsErrmsg = null;
        cowSIMaintain.Validate_Supp(this, lsErrmsg);
    }
```

Sorry forgot I left you hanging..  Hope you get this in time to be useful, It should do what you need, or at least point you in the right direction.